# Error adding bucket KMS encryption in S3

Tags: terraform

I have Terraform code that I've added KMS encryption to.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket = "${var.bucket}${var.envSuffix}"
  acl    = "private"
  tags {
      Name = "${var.bucket}${var.envSuffix}"
      Environment = "${var.env}"
  }

  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        kms_master_key_id = "${var.kms_key_id}"
        sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run an apply, I get the error:

```
invalid or unknown key: server_side_encryption_configuration
```

I'm running Terraform v0.11.0.  Why isn't Terraform recognizing server_side_encryption_configuration as a valid element?  I assume it is referring to the server_side_encryption_configuration element and not the kms_master_key_id element.

I've tested without the kms_master_key_id element at all and get exactly the same error, so it doesn't appear to be related to an incorrect value assigned to the kms_master_key_id element.

Comment: It's not the Terraform version that matters but the AWS provider version instead. `server_side_encryption_configuration` was introduced in 1.6.0

Comment: Originally I was running against "aws-cli/1.11.25 Python/2.7.9 Windows/7 botocore/1.4.82".  I've updated CLI and now am running "aws-cli/1.14.44 Python/2.7.9 Windows/7 botocore/1.8.48".   Still, the same results.

Comment: Can you upgrade the AWS Provider version and try? `provider "aws" {version = "~> 1.9.0"}`

Comment: Thanks Sai!  That was indeed the problem.  Its now working.

Comment: Thanks also to ydaetskcoR for providing the correct answer (didn't mean to slight you).  I simply didn't understand what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously a dated question but for the help of passer-bys, the terraform module "`aws_s3_server_side_encryption_configuration`" is to be used and not the server_side_encryption...block inside the aws_s3 module, which is deprecated.

Like,

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "bEncryption"{ 
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.sourceBucket.id
    rule{
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        sse_algorithm = "aws:kms"
      }    
    }
...
}
```

It should ideally have been showing up a warning and not an error unless the $var key variable contains the string "server_side_encryption_configuration".

Answer (score 0):

`kms_master_key_id` should be the ARN more than the key name.

Can you confirm if you do the right setting in `var.kms_key_id`?

```
   kms_master_key_id = "${aws_kms_key.mykey.arn}"
```

> kms_master_key_id - (optional) The AWS KMS master key ID used for the SSE-KMS encryption. This can only be used when you set the value of sse_algorithm as aws:kms. The default aws/s3 AWS KMS master key is used if this element is absent while the sse_algorithm is aws:kms.

Comment: I've tried hard coding the ID and the ARN and got the same error both times.  I'm unclear whether Terraform even gets to that point of if its choking on the value.  I believe it is complaining that server_side_encryption_configuration is an invalid element.

Comment: which version of terraform?

Comment: I'm running Terraform v0.11.0.

Comment: I removed the kms_master_key_id element altogether and still am getting the same error, so it seems to be confirming that the "server_side_encryption_configuration" is somehow causing the problem.